# How to create a 5x5 matrix with increasing numbers in java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

i am trying to create a 5x5 matrix using for loops but i can not do it, i've been looking for it for a day but still i could not figure it out, so i gave up and asking for a help now.
 I need a matrix like;

```
 1  0  0  0  0
 2  3  0  0  0
 4  5  6  0  0
 7  8  9 10  0
11 12 13 14 15
```

I did the matrix full of zeros;

```
 public class ExampleClass{ 
 public static void main(String args[]) { 



    int[][] Example =    new int [5][5];

        for(int i=0;i<Example.length;i++){
            for(int k=0;k<Example.length;k++)
            System.out.print(Example[i][k]+" ");
            System.out.println(); 

       }
    }
}
output:
           0  0  0  0  0  
           0  0  0  0  0  
           0  0  0  0  0  
           0  0  0  0  0  
           0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with another variable, let's say it's called `c`:

```
int c = 1;
for(int i=0;i<Example.length;i++){
  for(int k=0;k<Example.length;k++)
    if (k <= i) {
      System.out.print(c++ +" ");
     } else {
       System.out.print(0 +" ");   
     }
  System.out.println(); 
}
```

Or if you want also the proper spacing:

```
int c = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < Example.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < Example.length; k++) {
        if (k <= i) {
            if (c < 10) System.out.print(" ");
            System.out.print(" " + c++);
        } else {
            System.out.print("  " + 0);
        }

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This outputs:

```
  1  0  0  0  0
  2  3  0  0  0
  4  5  6  0  0
  7  8  9 10  0
 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. this example made me crazy, you just saved my mental health haha.

Comment: This will only print the pattern but it will not initialize `Example[][]`.

Comment: Just add `int[][] Example =    new int [5][5];` before as it was in the question :)

Comment: @Balastrong - You are still not there. The statement, `int[][] Example = new int [5][5];` will initialize the array with default values which are `0`; not with the values which you have printed. If you want to use the array later in the program, all the indices will have `0` instead of the values which you have printed.

Answer (score 1):

The values are below the main diagonal, including it. All these values are on the positions which `i` is less or equal to `j`, where `i` is the line index and `j` is the column index in the example below.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    int[][] m = new int[5][5];
    int count = 1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < m.length; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m.length; j++ ) {
            if ( j <= i ) {
                m[i][j] = count++;
            } else {
                m[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < m.length; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < m.length; j++ ) {
            System.out.printf( "%2d ", m[i][j] );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

If you just need to print the values, you can do something like:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    int size = 5;
    int count = 1;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
            if ( j <= i ) {
                System.out.printf( "%2d ", count++ );
            } else {
                System.out.printf( "%2d ", 0 );
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] example = new int[5][5];
        int x = 1;

        // Initialize
        for (int i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= i && k < example[i].length; k++) {
                example[i][k] = x++;
            }
        }

        // Display
        for (int i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < example[i].length; k++) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", example[i][k]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
  1  0  0  0  0
  2  3  0  0  0
  4  5  6  0  0
  7  8  9 10  0
 11 12 13 14 15
```

Also, always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the variable, `Example` should be named as `example`.